# usb stick "not authorized to perform"

Tags: linux, usb, automount, nis

Hello (sorry for my poor english).
I have a fresh install of desktop clients linux mint 19.2 with a NIS authentication.
Local users can plug usb-stick and it automount without problem.
On the other hand, NIS users get this message:
"Not authorized to perform operation".

With NIS user, if i type "groups" i get:

```
adm disk mail dialout cdrom audio dip video plugdev systemd-journal
```

i tried to modify /etc/security/group.conf and /etc/pam.d/login like here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1560569
but it does nothing.
Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you say NIS authentication? Good God. I sincerely hope your organization is getting rid of it ASAP. That went out of style in the 1990s.

Comment: It's education organization, and that works perfectly until now. :)